# Informations missing on products facebook commerce api sdk php

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to receive all the informations of my products on facebook commerce but i receive only ID, retailer OD and Name

```
// Initialize the API with your access token
Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);

// Get your catalog
$catalog = new productCatalog($catalog_id);

// Get all products from the catalog
$products = $catalog->getProducts();
var_dump($products);
return $products;
```

that i have receive

```
"data": [
      {
         "id": "5859556270839159",
         "name": "\u003CPRODUCT_TITLE>",
         "retailer_id": "438710724807297"
      },
      {
         "id": "6216757465069427",
         "name": "superbe test car",
         "retailer_id": "h4i3ujgd0h"
      }
],
```